# is it possible to play a Japanese Xbox 360 game on a US Xbox 360 console?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

If I were to buy a Japanese Xbox 360 game and have it shipped, would I be able to play it on an US console out of the box?

If not, how would I go about doing so, if it's possible all?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a compatibility list. Try PlayAsia's comp list: http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-00-3-xbox360_compatibility_guide-49-fr.html. It's all game-specific.

Comment: @kotzekot I think the title of the other question is a red herring; this isn't a dupe, both the US and Japan use NTSC IIRC. That said, as written this question is a bit too broad. I've edited it to be a bit more targeted.